# How to reduce/filter a Column in a Spark DataFrame (Java) based on the length of the Column?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, connector

Using Spark 1.5.1 with spark-cassandra-connector-java and the Spark SQL DataFrame apis, what is the best way to filter out String columns that are less than or greater than a given length?

I am trying to do something like this

```
DataFrame df = context.sql("select key from mytable where key is not null")
DataFrame fdf = df.filter(functions.length(df.col("key").gt(10))))
```

How does the the functions.length(Column) api work?  It takes a Column in and returns a Column, but what happens with the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A column is what you need to apply a predicate to. So change the parenthesis

```
DataFrame fdf = df
 .filter(
   functions.length(df.col("key"))
   .gt(10)
)
```

What this does is apply a predicate based on the column Key. First we change the column key to a column of Length(key). Basically applying the function to all values in the column

```
[ "bird", "cat", "mouse" ] -> [ 4, 3, 5 ]
```

Then since we now have a numeric column we apply a greater than predicate to that column

```
[ 4 > 10, 3 > 10, 5 > 10 ] -> [ False, False, False ]
```

The boolean is used to determine whether the predicate passes or fails.

2) Why not just do the check in sql

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test.common WHERE LENGTH(key) > 10")
```

Gets all the values where the length of key is greater than 10

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  I had referred to the DataStax documentation at this [link]{https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlSupportedSyntax.html}  and didnt see the LENGTH keyword/function listed there.  Both alternatives work, but I had simplified the example for this post, so the one i will need to use is the example with the filter function.